# Getting a module ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a class (module) in another js file in the same folder which looks like this.

```
class MessageModule{

constructor(){

}

sayHello(){
    alert('Hello from msg');
}

}

 module.exports = MessageModule;
```

However, I am not able to require it in the main js file.

```
let $ = require('jquery');
global.jQuery = $;
let bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
let messageModule = require('message');


messageModule.sayHello();
```

How should I go about exporting this, or any class?

Thank you.

Comment: `sayHello` is a method in the class prototype. You need an instance of `MessageModule` or make it static.

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the class definition. You'll need to create an instance to reach any non-static method there. Static methods can be reached from the class object.

So, it's either:

```
class MessageModule{

    constructor(){

    }

    static sayHello(){
        alert('Hello from msg');
    }

}

module.exports = MessageModule;
```

Or:

```
let $ = require('jquery');
global.jQuery = $;
let bootstrap = require('bootstrap');
let messageModule = require('message')();


messageModule.sayHello();
```

Comment: Notice you should never use a `class` that has only static members.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class MessageModule {
    constructor() {

    }

    sayHello() {
        alert('hello from msg')
    }
}
```

Call that class in another page:

```
<script>
    import {Message} from "/scripts/message.js";

    var message = new Message();
    message.sayHello();

    // or

    //import {MessageModule} from "/scripts/message.js";

    //var message = new MessageModule();
    //message.sayHello();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! But when I changed the content in my sayHello function from alert, to a test like $('body').append('test'). It said $ is not defined, even though I have defined on the first line in my main script, do you know?

Comment: @BjarneHansen That may be you have refered the jquery file after `messenger.js` file